sqlalchemy python - sqlalchemy ignores datetime.utcnow() and datetime.now(timezone.utc) and sets value to None
Following a tutorial with which previously had no such problem. Here's the python code:
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, flash, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime, timezone

app = Flask(__name__)

SECRET_KEY = "SECRET_KEY"
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = SECRET_KEY
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///site.db"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default="default.jpg")
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)

    posts = db.relationship("Post", backref="author", lazy="subquery")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"

Here's the terminal input:
>>> from myapp1 import app, db, User, Post 
>>> with app.app_context():
>>>     post1 = Post(title="title1", content="content1", user_id=1)
                                                                
>>> post1
>>> Post('title1', 'None')

The same thing happening with date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now(timezone.utc)).
Is there some mistake in my code that makes it return None? If not, is there any other way now to return DateTime now value in sqlalchemy? Thanks in advance!

start with providing a [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example]

Did it! Sorry if it wasn't enough, I thought it was a common outdating thing

The default is computed when the session is flushed (or committed, which will implicitly flush the session). Since the code in the question does not flush or commit the session (or even add the object to a session), the default is not computed. This makes sense if you consider that some defaults may be SQL expressions which must be evaluated by the database, not Python.
There is an error in the code in the question: default=datetime.now(timezone.utc) will be evaluated only once, when the module code is executed by the interpreter, so every Post created will have the same default value.  Do default=lambda: datetime.now(timezone.utc) instead (or use functools.partial) to have the default evaluated independently for each instance.
